# WebSocket connection to 'wss://mydomain.com/ws' failed

Tags: node.js, reactjs, websocket, create-react-app, wss

I just began making a new domain for a client using ReactJS. I built the app using create-react-app, and I configured the React start script to run over port 443 so I could develop over HTTPS. The React app is running fine, but when I view the console in Chrome developer tools, I get a periodic error message "WebSocket connection to 'wss://mydomain.com/ws' failed:

[picture of error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kc6mV.png)

I did not set up anything in the node http-server or in the react code to "handle" anything going to /ws. Is WebSockets something I have to configure manually and that's why I keep getting a connection error? I just find it strange that create-react-app would enable a feature by default without it being at least fully-configured to the point of not generating errors.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Hello, did you find a fix for this?

Comment: I did not! However, I realized after posting this that it is an issue that only occurs when running the dev server. If I build and run the app from a separate express / node server in a "production" environment, the error goes away. So I just wrote a bash script to do all that for me and have been testing "in production". I eventually need to figure it out though because it gets time consuming to build every time I need to test.